# When I add a new row to an excel table it changes the range of my previous cells formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm making a table to generate product SKUs, and I am using a table so that it expands the formula automatically but whenever i add a new row the previous rows formula changes to the same range as the new one.

> =VLOOKUP([@Categoria],Table1,2,FALSE)&TEXT(COUNTIF($D$2:D5,[@Categoria]),"00000")

if that formula was on cell D5 and I add a new row D5 range would change to count until D6, If I add an aditional cell both D5 and D6 range would change to count until D7 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work by making the following change

> =+VLOOKUP(D4,Table1,2,FALSE)& TEXT(COUNTIF($D$2:INDEX(D:D,ROW( )),D4),"00000")

Comment: You don't need the D4 in the Index function. You can just omit that argument.

Comment: It would be optimal to point out what is the nature of this problem. Then tell what is the method you used to fix it. As it is right now, I doubt this post would be of any use to anybody else than you or someone using your file.

Comment: When adding a new row to the table, it will automatically update the formula for every cell in that column, changing the range in which the formula was expected to work.

Comment: I used index to set the range of countif() by giving it as reference the whole D column and as row number the row() to get the current row the formula is in.  

D4 is not part of the index function.